# JAVA EE glassfish include WAR inside EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, war

I have a `JAVA EE` Project, containing both `EJB` and `WAR` projects inside of it.

I want to be able to access `WAR` project class from the `EJB` project class.
I have access the other way ( I can access ejb class from war).

Is that possibble? How can this be done?

Thank's In Advance.

Comment: AFAICT it has nothing to do with project(or output) types. Probably ejb jar was just added to war project's classpath. You should add war project to classpath in order to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have got an EAR with two modules inside, WAR and EJB JAR. As both modules are independent, they shouldn't depend on each other. What you want to do is possible via MANIFEST.MF Class-Path entry in module META-INF folder, but I strongly discourage you to do so.

You can re-factor you application to following structure:

```
EAR/
   ejb-app.jar
   war-app.jar
   lib/
      common-libraries.jar
```

Just putyour common libraries to separate JAR (regular java project), and add it to ejb-app and war-app classpath.

Alternatively you can implement EJB's in WAR project as they are supported in WAR since Java EE6.